# Почему если указать data_seek один раз, то в следующий раз данные выведутся из другой строки?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

У меня есть таблица, которая имеет столбцы number и balance.
Я хочу вывести данные, хранящиеся в них на страницу.

Почему-то если $result->data_seek($i) указать один раз, то ячейка из столбца balance выведется из той же строки, а ячейка из столбца number выведется уже из следующей.

Я пришел к выводу, что либо data_seek(), либо fetch_assoc() как-то сдвигают указатель на следующую строку. Ведь если взывать data_seek() также перед выводом ячейки из второго столбца, то все будет ОК. Прав ли я, что одна из функций сдвигает указатель на следующую строку? Если нет, то почему тогда так происходит?

```
    <?php
         require_once "reg file/login.php";
         $connection = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
         if ($connection->connect_error) die("Ошибка подключения к БД.");
         $query = "SELECT * FROM accounts";
         $result = $connection->query($query);

         if (!$result) die("Fatal Error");
         $rows = $result->num_rows;
         for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
             $result->data_seek($i); //Если написать data_seek() только здесь, 
//то ячейка из столбца balance будет выдана из следующей строки. 
             echo "number: " . htmlspecialchars($result->fetch_assoc()["number"]) . "<br>";
             echo "balance: " . htmlspecialchars($result->fetch_assoc()["balance"]) . "<br>";

         }
```

Comment: data_seek($i)  на строку $i, fetch_assoc() - на следующую

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Я читал документацию к обоим функциям, но не увидел, чтобы там было написано про то, что какая-то из них смещает указатель на новую строку

Comment: " fetch_assoc() - на следующую" - хорошо, я понял, спасибо

Comment: явно, действительно, не написано, но из примера `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {` вроде, очевидно

Comment: зачем вы это вообще делаете? `foreach ($result as $row)` и в путь, выводить сразу из `$row`.

Comment: @Мелкий ок, спасибо